# How to set up user authorization by certificate on SharePoint 2016?

Tags: certificate, authorization

I need to authorize users not only by login/password but also by individual certificates. How can I create such certificates manually and configure SharePoint to prompt certificate for authorization and if there is no one then propmt login/password?

Please don't suggest ADFS. I know that I can use ADFS-server which can authorize by certificate, but it is not our case. I need simple solution: user enters site url and SharePoint automatically authorize user by certificate if it present (without extra clicks) or prompt login/password it it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any other way for this .

Configuring ADFS and using SAML based tokens for the authentication is the only preferred option for this kind of requirement.

But again for using this you need to go through a lot of planning.